# Just 'peek' at the clipboard

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to get data from the clipboard but not remove it, so another method or application can get it?

I have a third party component where I can override the paste method, but I can not change what `base.Paste()` is doing. So I will try to save the clipboard data before I call `base.Paste()` and after that do some operation with the data.

Comment: If it is copied it will stay in the clipboard even if you were to use Clipboard Methods (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) to access it..

Comment: this is for WPF https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Clipboard_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the standard .Net Implementation.. why do you want to use a third party assembly?

```
  mystring = Clipboard.GetText(System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Text)

  myObject = Clipboard.GetData(format);
```

won`t remove the Text in the clipboard.

You can also get the Clipboard Content and Copy it back to the clipboard after your third party component removed if:

```
        data = Clipboard.GetData(format);
        //run 3rd party function
        Clipboard.SetData(format, data);
```